# NoClassDefFoundError for apache poi HWPF 5.0

Tags: java, apache-poi, hwpf

I need to add support of word document editing in standalone jar.
I add apache-poi-poi-5.0.0.jar and poi-scratchpad-5.0.0.jar to class path libraries and classpath. But still got this error on execuition. What i miss in configuration?
[image: libraries]
[image: class path]
[image: artifacts]
[image: error]
I use IDEA ide.

Comment: add you sure the poi classes are being copied into your standalone jar?

Comment: yeap they are in root of jar

Comment: Jars-in-jars isn't supported by the standard classloader, you need either a custom classloader or to build a fatjar instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add maven to project
2. Build uberjar with http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/